# How to create a query that performs well and returns 10k records

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have the following query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "google_contacts".* 
FROM "google_contacts" 
WHERE "google_contacts"."user_id" = 1201
```

This query ends up taking a lot of time, below are the results:

```
Seq Scan on google_contacts  (cost=0.00..394.99 rows=9999 width=183)
    (actual time=0.008..2.038 rows=9999 loops=1)
      Filter: (user_id = 1201)
Total runtime: 2.552 ms
```

This table only has 10 columns and has an index on user_id... Any thoughts on why this is taking so long to run? Thanks

Comment: The type of the `user_id` column is `int`, right? Oh, and the index on `user_id` should include no other columns...

Comment: Does it really takes "so long to run" ? The query itself takes 2.5 ms to get all 10k results.

Comment: First, we need to see column and index definitions if we are to help you optimize your queries.  Second, there is no need to quote your table and column names.  `google_contacts.user_id` is perfectly fine and is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here? It looks as though the query takes ~2.5ms to run. I wouldn't characterize that as 'a lot of time'.

It is interesting that the query optimizer has chosen not to use your index on user_id (since the explain mentions doing a seq scan instead of an index scan), but my understanding is that it will choose whichever method it (the optimizer) thinks will run most efficiently, and that there's not a whole lot you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

If query returns too many rows, sequence scan will be more effective than using index. In this case You can improve performance using other methods. On the other hand, the bottleneck can be you network connection.